# How can I get my google script to to read a document?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to take lines from a spreadsheet and use them to create a new document, each with 4 lines on each page.

When I run it, I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getSheetByName')"

here is what I have:

```
function generateHorrorPromptsDoc() {
  var sheetName = "666 horror creative writing prompts"; // Replace with the name of your sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var data = ss.getRange(1, 1, ss.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var docName = "My Horror Writing Prompts"; // Replace with the name of the document you want to create
```

I have quadruple checked that all the document names are correct, all the permissions are active, that I have signed up for Google Docs API, and that there are no extra spaces etc...

I am very new at this, thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you running this from a Spreadsheet and trying to put rows in a Doc or are you running this from a Doc and trying to pull values from a Spreadsheet?  Your script seems incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function generateHorrorPromptsDoc() {
  var sheetName = "Sheet0"; 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var data = ss.getRange(1, 1, ss.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the name that the sheet had, and put it to work with the active sheet, additionally, I added code, so that it would create the doc for you. I hope it works for you.

```html
function generateHorrorPromptsDoc() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var docName = "My Horror Writing Prompts"; // Replace with the name of the document you want to create

  // Creates a new document in Google Docs
  var newDoc = DocumentApp.create(docName);
  var body = newDoc.getBody();

  // Iterates through each promo title and adds it to the document
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    body.appendParagraph(data[i][0]);
    body.appendParagraph(""); // Adds an empty line between each title
  }

  // Saves and closes the new document
  newDoc.saveAndClose();
}
```